# Joining two server in SSIS Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, join, ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Some part of my data was moved to another server. For this reason I have to change query in my OLE DB Source in SSIS. I use this moved data to return 3 columns and filter my whole data.
I also have to use dynamic query, because for each day, I have few version of data and I need to take the newest. For this I use Foreach Loop which iterate through data and assign the newest version to filter. Because of this I think that Lookup transformation won't work for me.

The query looks like:

```
SELECT
x,
y,
...
a.moved_data
a.moved_data2
a.moved_data3
FROM old_server
...
LEFT JOIN new_server a
...
WHERE a.filter = ?
```

I can't use Merge Join because this query is to big to be sorted.

Because joined table have milions of rows I need also to use seek predicate on join and where.

All of my source are SQL Server 2008R. I also have linked this server in MS.

How to join table from different server in this case?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I look for solution to perform this join without sorting and with possibility to use dynamic query.

Comment: SSIS doesn't join. The SQL statement joins. Joining between linked servers though is a *very bad idea*, essentially you are copying the join fields from server A to server B and perform the join there. It's easier and faster to copy the relevant rows in the first place, then do the join localy

Comment: Also, why dynamic? Why don't you use parameters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't have SSIS parameters in this version of MS.

Comment: All supported SQL Server versions have parameters. I'm not 100% certain about 2000. 2005 though definitely had them.

Comment: You meant variables? I use it, but I don't have parameters in my version https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh213214(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @BNPTestovir parameters exist since at least 2005. The link you posted is irrelevant, it isn't about query parameters, it's about package parameters

Comment: So I used it in WHERE clause, but I can't parameterized my whole query -it's longer than 4000 char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a Lookup transformation?  Select stuff from old server.  Do a Lookup to the new server table (filtering if necessary - on the NEW Server table), with Redirect No Matches to NoMatchOutput.

Comment: How I can pass SSIS variable to Lookup?

Comment: You can put variables into the dataflow as derived columns, then "join" to the Lookup reference table using these columns (as well as your normal join columns)

Comment: Can you give more details how I can do it?

Comment: Using a Derived Column transformation, add the variables you want to use to filter the reference set into the dataflow, as new columns.  Set up the Lookup to join to the reference (remote) set on both your "usual" join columns, and on these columns to the filter columns in the reference set.

Comment: As I understood you correctly, this solution allows me to join whole table and after it, filter using dynamic expression. What I need is filter this table remotely and after it returns filtered data to my main (local) server.

Comment: No, the join would be on the filter expressions as well, so that the entire table _shouldn't be_ pulled across from the remote server.  In terms of performance, though, the database engine might well pull in the whole table and then filter it.  Impossible to tell without doing some diagnostics. You might be better off transferring the remote table data (or rather, just the filtered portion of it) to your local server in SSIS, and then joining to that.